# Changing color of an unlocked cell, in a locked sheet

Tags: vba, excel, events

I'm dealing with a strange problem.

My code creates a locked sheet, with a few unlocked cells.

The code also creates a `Worksheet_Change` sub, that changes the interior color of the edited cell.

It works fine, but when i close the file and open it again, although the unlocked cell is editable, the `Worksheet_Change` sub gives an error for changing the color :

> "Application-defined or object-defined error".

---

When i tried changing the value insted of the color in the sub, it did work.

Locking the sheet:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(atar).Cells(exlRow, 7).Locked = False
Worksheets(atar).Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, Password:="shani" 'lock sheet
```

Created sub:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `AllowFormattingCells:=True` to allow cells coloring :

```
Worksheets(atar).Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, Password:="shani"
```